# Change name of uploaded file at a later point in time - django

Tags: django, file-upload

Is it possible to change the name of the file after it has been uploaded. And the change has to be done not at the time when the file is being uploaded but at a later stage. In a different function I process that file and have to change the name of the file. But it seems I can't change the name of the file, unlike other attributes of the object.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find something like this: ?

```
class BaseImage(models.Model):
    """
        Base Image model
    """

    path_format_str = u'%(id_prefix)s/gallery-%(object_id)s/%(image_name)s'

    def upload_to(self, original_name):

        return self.path_format_str % {
            'id_prefix': str(self.object_id).zfill(6)[:3],
            'object_id': self.object_id,
            'image_name': sanitize_file_name(original_name),
        }

    file_data = models.ImageField(
        blank=True,
        upload_to=upload_to,
        verbose_name=u'soubor s obrázkem',
        help_text=mark_safe(u'Připojte fotku - formát JPG, bla bla bla ,...'),
        max_length=255
    )
```